# InfluxQL and missing length function

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I must be missing something really simple and obvious but some basic InfluxQL string functions are not working for me. Trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT length(state::string) FROM "autogen"."state" WHERE entity_id::tag='klimatyzator_gabinet'
```

gives me:

```
InfluxDB Error: undefined function length()
```

while this works:

```
SELECT (state::string) FROM "autogen"."state" WHERE entity_id::tag='klimatyzator_gabinet'
```

I assume `length` should exist based on https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud-serverless/reference/sql/functions/string/#length

Some more info about my setup: this is Home Assistant with InfluxDB and Grafana addons. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `InfluxDB Cloud Serverless` and not different InfluxDB version?

Comment: Ok, didn't assume "InfluxDB Cloud Serverless" is something that significantly different from other versions, just that it is a matter of hosting. Anyway, based on  https://github.com/hassio-addons/addon-influxdb/blob/main/influxdb/Dockerfile I get I am using version 1.8.10. So the question would be: is there any chance to get similar query with length function in version 1.8.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use doc for `InfluxDB Cloud Serverless`

> InfluxDB Cloud Serverless powered by the IOx storage engine, which offers different functionality than InfluxDB Cloud powered by the TSM storage engine.

But you are using `InfluxDB v1.8`, so you have to use different doc https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1/ - this version doesn't have `length` function, so error `undefined function length()` is correct.